# Search items in the listbox using index

Tags: c#, winforms, listbox

I am doing a project that uses listbox, I can add items, delete items, update items but I can't search,
this is my code for search

```
string search = Person.listperson[listBox1.SelectedIndex].lastname;
            foreach (String s in search)
            {
                if (s.Equals(textBox6.Text))
                {
                     //show searched items
                    MessageBox.Show("Success!");
                }
            }
```

can you help me with this? 
thanks :)

I have here a code for search,
But it does not apply in the button, how can I apply this on the button?

```
private void textBox6_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index = listBox1.FindString(this.textBox6.Text);
            if (0 <= index)
            {
                listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
            }
        }
```

Comment: I think, I can't use the 'foreach' :(

Comment: What is Person.listperson is it another listbox? I am a little confused about exactly what you are doing. It looks like you are selecting an item in listBox1 then using its index to select a last name out of Something?? which is giving you just one string which does not implement IEnumerable so you can not use foreach.

Comment: here is my code for search :D

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try something like this, add a click event to your button and put your code in it. This works for me.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    int index = listBox1.FindString(textBox6.Text);
    if (index > -1)
    {
        listBox1.SelectedIndex = index;
    }
}
```

Comment: I added a click event example, your code should work wether or not it is in a TextChanged Event or a Click Event.

Comment: I think it does not apply in the button

Comment: That code will work in the button click event with no problems. I am assuming that you are still using textBox6 as the source of your search string.

Comment: Yeah your right, I forgot to erase the codes in the textbox6 event :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what you're trying to do exactly, but here's some samples.
Also, start giving variables useful names. If you come back to this code in a month you'll have no idea what's going on there or what `textBox6` is.

To find a string (`textBox6`) in the entire `listperson` collection:

```
var list = Person.listperson.Where(p => p.lastname.Contains(textBox6.Text));
```

To check if a specific item in `listperson` has a partial `textBox6` value:

```
var search = Person.listperson[listBox1.SelectedIndex].lastname;
bool success = search.Contains(textBox6.Text);
```

Or if you'd rather compare the values:

```
bool success = (search == textBox6.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can foreach char in a string

```
string s = "Blippy you";
        foreach (char item in s)
        {

        }
```

but anywho. try Text.RegularExpressions for string matching.

Answer (score -1):

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    if (listBox1.FindString("Your String in Textbox 6") != -1)
     {
        MessageBox.Show("Success!");
     }
}
```

Comment: You could provide some more context... [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)